# How would I cite a dataset with BibTeX?

Tags: bibtex, bibdesk

I want to output something like this:

> Pew Research Center for the People & the Press. (2008). April 2012 Values Survey [Data file]. Available from Pew Research Center for the People & the Press Web site: http://www.people-press.org/category/datasets/

How would I enter that into [BibDesk](http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/)? I use BibDesk to manage my citations.

Answer (score 2):

Does BibDesk have the 'unpublished' option?  Will this work in the appropriate fields?

```
author = Pew Research Center for...
year = 2008
title = April 2012 Values Survey [Data file]
note = Available from Pew...http://www....
```

This should work manually in a bib file (with appropriate syntax, of course), so I can only assume it will also in Bibdesk.

Comment: Maybe the `misc` "catch-all" type?

Comment: Ah, that's probably the more 'elegant' way to do it.

Comment: For visitors from **THE FUTURE**, there is now a dedicated `dataset` type available in biblatex. (since version 3.13, late 2019). If you're using BibDesk, it doesn't appear in it's drop down list of types, you'll need to add it as custom type in the application preferences, under Fields, Custom BibTeX Types and Fields. (See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/880, and page 10 of the biblatex documentation.)