# How to cite data?

Tags: bibtex, citing

[Data can be cited](http://www.datacite.org/whycitedata).  Citeable data has fully persistent DOI's that link to recognised data repositories.  This ensures that the data used in scientific publications can be obtained and re-used in the future.

Is there any specific way to cite data using the bibtex file format (using either bibtex or biber), apart from `@misc`?

Comment: Does that help? http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=10865

Comment: Well, in this case those are not written documents at all.  But perhaps that doesn't matter.

Comment: Can't you technically create new `@type`s with `biblatex`?  I think I've read that somewhere.

Comment: Related, I suppose, though this is more specific: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109127/how-would-i-cite-a-dataset-with-bibtex

Comment: Do you literally want to cite *data* (i.e., individual quantitative or qualitative data points), or do you want to cite the *name* and *source* of the dataset? If it's the latter, what would be wrong with using the `@misc` entry type?