# Cite dataset with bibtex using Mendeley

Tags: bibtex, doi

The question was already asked ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109127/how-would-i-cite-a-dataset-with-bibtex) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128270/how-to-cite-data?lq=1)) but I was not able to find a proper answer:

How can I cite a dataset with bibtex?

I'm using [Zenodo](http://zenodo.org/) as a place to put my data, and I have a [DOI](http://www.doi.org/). So I include the DOI and the URL, I put Zenodo as the publisher and I'm a bit blocked to explicitly show in the bibliography that this is a dataset.

When I use the "report" type, it is written "Technical report" in my bibliography. With data, I would use a "misc" type, but I would like to write, similarly to "Technical report", "Dataset".

How would you cite a dataset? Anyone already met this issue? Not in the bibliography?

Zenodo official recommendation is:

> Last name, First name (year). Title. ZENODO.
>   [10.5281/zenodo.8492](http://dx.doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.8492)

But their bibtex exporter does not work.

Comment: Can't you use the `note` field to specify that it is a dataset? I'm not entirely clear why `@misc` isn't suitable. An example would probably help.

Comment: I am using this to cite code on github via zenodo in miktex via bibtex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally chose to use "misc" type with:

> Howpublished = {Dataset on Zenodo},

It gives:

> Last name, A. (year). Title, Dataset on Zenodo. URL: http ://dx.doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.8492

I don't know if it is the best or most common way to quote a dataset, but it is the way I'll do it for now.

One side comment: [the "Howpublished" field seems impossible to access from Mendeley](http://feedback.mendeley.com/forums/4941-general/suggestions/436675-use-howpublished-for-urls-in-bibtex-export).

I'm still interested in any reference about how to quote datasets.